# How do i pivot wider and count the occurrence of a pair by two columns?

Tags: r, igraph

Check out the data frame here

```
dt <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 
5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7), V1 = c("ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "GHI", 
"GHI", "JKL", "JKL", "DEF", "ABC", "MNO", "GHI", "GHI", "ABC", 
"DEF", "DEF", "GHI", "MNO", "MNO", "ABC"), V2 = c("DEF", "MNO", 
"MNO", "JKL", "DEF", "ABC", "DEF", "ABC", "ABC", "JKL", "JKL",                                                                                               
"ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "GHI", "MNO", "MNO", "ABC", "JKL", "JKL"
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

for example in column V1, ABC appears 5 times and in V2, DEF appears 5 times as well. However they are paired up three times. I would like to create a count column that counts their pair no matter what column (V1 or V2) they belong in.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how the final output should be? Do you want to count the occurrence of (ABC, DEF) and (DEF, ABC) across all possible colums not counting the ID column?

Comment: Yes. I want to count ABC and DEF occurrence, whichever direction. not counting ID columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `table()` and add the result and its transpose together:

```
tbl <- table(dt[-1]) 

(cnts <- tbl + `diag<-`(t(tbl), 0))

     V2
V1    ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO
  ABC   0   3   2   3   2
  DEF   3   0   3   1   2
  GHI   2   3   0   1   1
  JKL   3   1   1   0   2
  MNO   2   2   1   2   0
```

To deduplicate and transform to a data frame:

```
cnts[upper.tri(cnts)] <- NA

subset(as.data.frame.table(cnts), !is.na(Freq))

    V1  V2 Freq
1  ABC ABC    0
2  DEF ABC    3
3  GHI ABC    2
4  JKL ABC    3
5  MNO ABC    2
7  DEF DEF    0
8  GHI DEF    3
9  JKL DEF    1
10 MNO DEF    2
13 GHI GHI    0
14 JKL GHI    1
15 MNO GHI    1
19 JKL JKL    0
20 MNO JKL    2
25 MNO MNO    0
```

Comment: I get this message Error in t.default(tbl) : argument is not a matrix

Comment: I did fix that part of the script and the remaining went through.

Answer (score 5):

## Update

```
dt[, c(2, 3, 1)] %>%
    graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) %>%
    get.adjacency(type = "upper") %>%
    graph_from_adjacency_matrix(weighted = TRUE) %>%
    get.data.frame()
```

gives

```
   from  to weight
1   ABC DEF      3
2   ABC GHI      2
3   DEF GHI      3
4   ABC JKL      3
5   DEF JKL      1
6   GHI JKL      1
7   ABC MNO      2
8   DEF MNO      2
9   GHI MNO      1
10  JKL MNO      2
```

---

I guess you can try the `igraph` option like below

```
library(igraph)
get.adjacency(
    graph_from_data_frame(dt[, -"ID"],
        directed = FALSE
    ),
    sparse = FALSE
)
```

which gives

```
    ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO
ABC   0   3   2   3   2
DEF   3   0   3   1   2
GHI   2   3   0   1   1
JKL   3   1   1   0   2
MNO   2   2   1   2   0
```

---

If you want to add a column indicating the counts, you can try

```
transform(
    dt,
    cnts = ave(ID, pmin(V1, V2), pmax(V1, V2), FUN = length)
)
```

which gives

```
   ID  V1  V2 cnts
 1:  1 ABC DEF    3
 2:  1 ABC MNO    2
 3:  1 DEF MNO    2
 4:  2 GHI JKL    1
 5:  2 GHI DEF    3
 6:  2 GHI ABC    2
 7:  2 JKL DEF    1
 8:  2 JKL ABC    3
 9:  2 DEF ABC    3
10:  3 ABC JKL    3
11:  4 MNO JKL    2
12:  5 GHI ABC    2
13:  5 GHI DEF    3
14:  5 ABC DEF    3
15:  6 DEF GHI    3
16:  6 DEF MNO    2
17:  6 GHI MNO    1
18:  7 MNO ABC    2
19:  7 MNO JKL    2
20:  7 ABC JKL    3
```

Comment: You see line 1 and 9 for example. I don't want it to count twice.

Comment: I'm going to take network analysis next semester and it requires us to learn `igraph`, so I think I'm going to have tons of question to ask you lol.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Sure, you are welcome! If you had graph theory background, I believe it would be much easier for you to learn `igraph`.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I studied it while I was at high school in a section of discrete mathematics, but so many years has passed. I think I'm a bit familiar or with a little bit of reviewing I could remember key features. I found a book called `statistical analysis of network data with R` published by springer but our main reference is `networks, crowds and markets`.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Haha, sounds interesting. Maybe we can learn `igraph` together if you have any `igraph` question. Please ping me when you want to share any interesting `igraph` problem.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Sure I will give you a heads-up before posting just like Anil and I however his questions are mostly unsolvable lol. Oh sure that would be a pleasure to learn from you. You are light years ahead of me, I have to start from square one :D

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding in the update you have line line 1 and 5 for ABC and DEF appear twice.

Answer (score 3):

In base R you could do something like:

```
codes = unique(c(dt$V1, dt$V2))
output = data.frame(code1 = character(0), code2 = character(0), occurances = integer(0))
for(i1 in 1:length(codes)){
    code1 = codes[i1]
    for(i2 in 1:i1){
        code2 = codes[i2]
        count = sum((code1==dt$V1 & code2 == dt$V2) | (code1==dt$V2 & code2 == dt$V1))
        output = rbind(output, data.frame(code1=code1, code2=code2, occurances=count))
    }
}
output
```

Which outputs:

```
   code1 code2 occurances
1    ABC   ABC          0
2    DEF   ABC          3
3    DEF   DEF          0
4    GHI   ABC          2
5    GHI   DEF          3
6    GHI   GHI          0
7    JKL   ABC          3
8    JKL   DEF          1
9    JKL   GHI          1
10   JKL   JKL          0
11   MNO   ABC          2
12   MNO   DEF          2
13   MNO   GHI          1
14   MNO   JKL          2
15   MNO   MNO          0
```

Comment: I'm getting Error: object of type ;closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Is `dt` still the same dataframe as in your example?